# Argparse positional argument '*'

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I need to parse a command line like the following

```
script.py apple banana -l list pineapple
```

The fruits should go to a list and the -n flag to another flag

I'm trying to solve this with

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('fruit', nargs = '*')
parser.add_argument('-l', dest = ls)
```

Using this example I got the following error:
unrecognized arguments pineapple

Note, using

```
script.py apple banana -l list
```

Works fine

Using nargs = argparse.REMAINDER
let to a strange behavior.

All parameters were put inside the "fruit" list.

Thanks

Comment: Where's `pineapple` supposed to go?  'apple' and 'banana' have filled the `fruit` argument.  There's no other positional argument to take that extra string.  In general using several variable `nargs` positional arguments has problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3.7 adds a `parse_intermixed_args` method

```
In [70]: parser = argparse37.ArgumentParser()
In [71]: parser.add_argument('fruit', nargs = '*');
    ...: parser.add_argument('-l', '--ls');
```

Your error - the `fruit` positional got used/filled by the first two strings.  There isn't a positional to take the last.

```
In [72]: parser.parse_args('apple banana -l list pinaple'.split())
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-l LS] [fruit [fruit ...]]
ipython3: error: unrecognized arguments: pinaple
...
```

`parse_known_args` returns those extras in another list rather than raise an error:

```
In [73]: parser.parse_known_args('apple banana -l list pinaple'.split())
Out[73]: (Namespace(fruit=['apple', 'banana'], ls='list'), ['pinaple'])
```

`intermixed` can handle the split 'positional':

```
In [74]: parser.parse_intermixed_args('apple banana -l list pinaple'.split())
Out[74]: Namespace(fruit=['apple', 'banana', 'pinaple'], ls='list')
```

Comment: Thank you, indeed seems that I've to use the version 3.7 so.